# How to Solve second order Differential Equation with two parts

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this two equations togather

```
x''[t]+ a^2 x[t]=0

;

(x'[t])^2+ b^2 (x[t])^2=0
```

I wrote this code but is not working

```
DSolve[{y''[x] == -z[x], (z'[x])^2 == -(y[x])^2, {y[x], z[x]}, x]
```

Comment: Try this: `DSolve[{y''[x] == -z[x], (z'[x])^2 == -(y[x])^2}, {y[x], z[x]}, x]`. (noting the closing brace!)

Comment: No it gave some error

Comment: And what is "some" error?

Comment: @user199315 Is y(x) infinitely differentiable?

Comment: As a note for next time: "some error" is not a response that helps people help you. It is better to put in the text of any error message you have seen instead.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica 11.3 produces the following, without any errors:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] == -z[x], (z'[x])^2 == -(y[x])^2}, {y[x], z[x]}, x] // 
  ToRadicals // TeXForm
```

> {{
>
> y[x] -> -(1/3)
>          I E^(-I x) (I + I E^(I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) + 
>          I E^(I x + (-1)^(5/6) x)) C[1] - 
>       1/3 E^(-I x) (-(-1)^(1/6) - (-1)^(5/6) + 
>          I E^(I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) - (-1)^(1/6) E^(I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) + 
>          I E^(I x + (-1)^(5/6) x) - (-1)^(5/6) E^(
>           I x + (-1)^(5/6) x)) C[2] - 1/3 E^(-I x) (-1 - (-1)^(2/3) E^(I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) + (-1)^(1/3) E^(I x + (-1)^(5/6) x)) C[3],
>
> z[x] -> 1/
>        3 E^(-I x) ((-1)^(1/3) - (-1)^(2/3) - E^(
>          I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) - (-1)^(2/3) E^(I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) - E^(
>          I x + (-1)^(5/6) x) + (-1)^(1/3) E^(I x + (-1)^(5/6) x)) C[
>         1] - 1/3 I E^(-I x) (-1 - (-1)^(2/3) E^(
>           I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) + (-1)^(1/3) E^(I x + (-1)^(5/6) x)) C[
>         2] - 1/3 I E^(-I x) (I + I E^(I x + (-1)^(1/6) x) + 
>          I E^(I x + (-1)^(5/6) x)) C[3]
>
> },{
>
> y[x] -> 
>      1/3 (E^(I x) + E^(-(-1)^(1/6) x) + E^(-(-1)^(5/6) x)) C[1] + 
>       1/3 (-I E^(I x) + (-1)^(5/6) E^(-(-1)^(1/6) x) + (-1)^(1/6)
>            E^(-(-1)^(5/6) x)) C[2] - 
>       1/3 (-E^(I x) - (-1)^(2/3) E^(-(-1)^(1/6) x) + (-1)^(1/3) E^(-(-1)^(5/6) x)) C[3],
>
> z[x] -> 1/
>        3 I (-I E^(I x) + (-1)^(5/6) E^(-(-1)^(1/6) x) + (-1)^(1/6)
>            E^(-(-1)^(5/6) x)) C[1] + 
>       1/3 I (-E^(I x) - (-1)^(2/3) E^(-(-1)^(1/6) x) + (-1)^(1/3)
>            E^(-(-1)^(5/6) x)) C[2] + 1/3 (E^(I x) + E^(-(-1)^(1/6) x) + E^(-(-1)^(5/6) x)) C[3]
>
> }}